If $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$ and $\Delta\vDash\varphi$ then $Γ ∩ Δ ⊨ \varphi$
Let $\Gamma$ be $\{p\}$ and $\Delta$ be $\{q\}$ and $\varphi$ be $p\lor q$, then $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$ and $\Delta\vDash\varphi$. However, $\Gamma\cap\varphi$ is the empty set $\{\}$ and $\{\} \not\vDash p\lor q$.
The answer sheet said this, but doesn't an empty set entail everything? Shouldn't this be true?

Why do you think an empty set entails everything?

The false formula $\bot$ entails everything. Contexts are interpreted as conjunctions of formulas, and the conjunction of an empty set is $\top$.

And it's easy to construct non-empty counterexamples as well. For example, ${p,p\rightarrow r, q\rightarrow r} \models r$ and ${q,p\rightarrow r, q\rightarrow r} \models r$ both hold, but ${p\rightarrow r, q\rightarrow r} \models r$ does not hold.
